# Azure Notification Hub Handle Multiple Registrations for same Tag and Resolve Duplicate Pushes

Tags: android, azure, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azureservicebus

- I want multiple devices to register for push notification using Azure Service Bus with same tag.
- But same device gets registered multiple times when the App gets uninstalled and reinstalled. leading to multiple pushes getting delivered to the same device.
- I want how to register multiple devices uniquely but with same tag.
- Also during app launch i register device every time. please provide me some solution how can i deal with multiple registrations and delete duplicate registrations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052010/deal-with-duplicate-entries-in-azure-notification-hub-for-the-same-device    I have the same problem but i want multiple devices should have unique entries for the same tag

Comment: Nobody can help for this concept because solution is base on your database structure as well as requirement.
I have also face this problem and solved using create a unique ID for each devices.

Comment: @SumitGarg can you give me some way to identify each and every device uniquely irrespective of platform